# How to extend each object in collection with new property with value of function result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Suppose my app has array of object type A:

```
{
    prop1: 11,
    prop2: 2222
}
```

How to add to each object of array new property which will contain value as the result of function. I know I can do it manually, but any clever function exist in AngularJS :)?

Comment: [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Comment: Look at [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) and [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you yourself have added uses `.map()` and `.extend()` for no goood reason. Since you are only adding one property, you can do this:

```
result.forEach(function (obj) {
    obj.iconname = getGameIconName(obj.gamename) + "_logo.png";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Angular forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function - see a demo below:

```js
var array = [{
    prop1: 11,
    prop2: 22
},{
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2
}];

angular.forEach(array,function(e){
  e.sum = e.prop1 + e.prop2;
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it in such way:

```
/*
     *private method preparing name of game icon
     */
    var getGameIconName = function(gameName) {

        return gameName.replace(/ /g, '_').toLowerCase();
    };

...
result = result.map(function(obj) {
            return angular.extend(obj, { iconname: getGameIconName(obj.gamename) + "_logo.png" });
        });
```

Comment: `map` function creates a new array - so if only adding a new property *is* what is all that is required, a `forEach` will do :)